# how to make sequence in standard form using forms personalization?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

i want to make sequence in tasks screen in projects module using forms personalization i have tried  to create a global variable and select the count (*) +1 but i didn't work and i have tried also to make the( task_number +1) and it didn't work also [the sequence will be here in the task number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0mut.png)

Comment: Where did you initiate the global variable and where did you assign it to the field?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in your block level ***pre-insert*** trigger.

```
declare   
  v_ref your_block.COLUMN_NAME%type; 
begin   
  select nvl(max(COLUMN_NAME),20170732)+ 1 
    into v_ref 
    from Tablename;
    :your_block.ref_no := v_ref;    
end;
```